# Delete file doesn't work with cors but upload works with cors with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using react-s3 for uploading and deleting file from s3.
When the bucket is public, it works fine for both methods but when it is set to private,
only upload file works and delete file throws error:

```
type: "cors"
url: "https://mylink.myfile"
redirected: false
status: 403
ok: false
statusText: "Forbidden"
```

Also this is what I put for CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

You must be generating the presigned URL for `putObject` only. Deletion does not supported through presigned URLs. it is only supported for `GET` and `PUT`. consider doing deletion using server side code after carefully checking whether or not the deletion should be allowed.